# File upload progress when backend service integrate with cloud storage

Tags: javascript, file-upload, progress-bar

I am working on a file upload component.

**Step 1**. Browser uploads a file to my own backend service

**Step 2**. Backend service will then upload this file to a cloud storage service.

And I want to track the uploading progress.

```
superagent
.post('/api/upload')
.send(formData)
.on('progress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.percent)
})
.end(function(err, res) {
  console.log('done')
})
```

I tried to use the code above, but `e.percent` would reach `100` when **Step 1** was done

What I want to `e.percent` will reach `100` when both steps are done.

Thanks.

Comment: Encountered the same problem. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Forget it... so sad